# WMS - Filter single layer

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to make a WMS call to geoserver which will create an image containing 2 layers foo & bar (foo is a layer group); however bar should be filtered based on featureid.

When I only load a single layer (e.g. bar) - I can use the filter method `&featureid=bar.1` but this same method doesn't work when you try to load multiple layers (e.g. foo & bar).

**Single Layer Filter**

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/foobar/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=bar&featureid=bar.1&styles=&bbox=349335.379999999,248145.919999682,349354.569999999,248170.619999681&width=768&height=735&srs=EPSG:27700&format=text%2Fhtml%3B%20subtype%3Dopenlayers#toggle
```

When I run:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/foobar/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=foo,bar&featureid=bar.1&styles=&bbox=349335.379999999,248145.919999682,349354.569999999,248170.619999681&width=768&height=735&srs=EPSG:27700&format=text%2Fhtml%3B%20subtype%3Dopenlayers#toggle
```

I get an error say that both layers need to be filtered. Any ideas on how to load multiple layers but only filter 1?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed it's a bug, I suggest you open a ticket at: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/summary

Comment: Hey Andrea, cheers for this. As advised I've raised a ticket - GEOS-7663